# Impact of music on working performance

Tags: performance, working-conditions

Is there any scientific research on impact of listening music when working to performance and quality of programming work?

It seems some employers consider listening to music as a negative condition.

Comment: Lots of comments here about site scope and other related questions - [meta] is the best place for those. This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32854/discussion-on-question-by-user626528-impact-of-music-on-working-performance) as well. Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, perception, and company policy. Whatever your boss says is what you should be doing. If you disagree you can ***try*** to persuade them otherwise, but remember that they make the rules. As for whether listening to music affects your productivity ... you know that best. Does it?

Comment: My past workplace was an open office. Music definitely helped me in concentrating when sometimes other people talks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There has been a lot of [work](http://www.helpscout.net/blog/music-productivity/) regarding this question.

The results have been [negative with regards to listening unfamiliar music](http://www.fastcompany.com/3032868/work-smart/how-music-affects-your-productivity).

Music which lack lyrics are [proved](http://www.fastcompany.com/3032868/work-smart/how-music-affects-your-productivity) to be more effective when it comes to improving productivity and getting things done.

There is this [famous research work](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/packages/pdf/business/LESIUKarticle2005.pdf) by Teresa Lesiuk. The abstract of the paper is self-explanatory:

> **ABSTRACT**  This study measured the effect of music listening on state
>   positive affect, work quality and time-on-task of computer information
>   systems developers. Effects of music on work performance, in this
>   case, software design, may be explained by increases in state positive
>   affect. Data from 56 (male = 41, female = 15) developers were obtained
>   from four different Canadian software companies. Data were collected
>   in the participants’ actual work environments over five weeks. Results
>   indicated that state positive affect and quality-of-work were lowest
>   with no music, while time-on-task was longest when music was removed.
>   Narrative responses revealed the value of music listening for positive
>   mood change and enhanced perception on design while working. Evidence
>   is provided of the presence of a learning curve in the use of music
>   for positive mood alteration. Overall, the study contributes to the
>   development of a model that aspires to elucidate music and workplace
>   interactions; as well, it has implications for organizational
>   practice.

Having said that, listening to music is multi-tasking and can affect your concentration and cognition, according to [these](http://www.forbes.com/sites/williamcraig/2014/10/17/science-is-divided-about-music-in-the-workplace-but-it-doesnt-matter/) [articles](http://qz.com/185337/the-complete-guide-to-listening-to-music-at-work/):

> Don’t fool yourself: Listening to music means that you are
>   multitasking. Any cognitive resources that your brain expends—on
>   understanding lyrics, processing emotions that are triggered by a
>   song, or remembering where you were when you first heard it—won’t be
>   available to help you work.

AFAIK:

If you already knew the lyrics of the song, then the brain doesn't need to make efforts to understand and learn them, so you can focus on being productive, and much better, it cuts out unnecessary noise around.

But, if you don't know the lyrics, then your brain is doing multi-tasking: trying to work and trying to understand the lyrics.

Comment: It would be great to know how much influence noise have on the outcome. The sample of 56 developers seems insignificant, especially when only from 4 software companies. Single rooms as work places with closed doors and no telephone or email alerts as opposed to open space offices or cubicles with a mixture of functions (sales, marketing, development in one room) would certainly change the outcome.

Comment: @malach Yeah, I do agree with you that the population chosen is insignificant and can be biased.  However, that's the only piece of literature I've found regarding this domain. :)

Comment: Why would you answer a question and then try to close it?  If you feel that this is off topic you shouldn't have answered it.  If you changed your mind then just delete the answer.  It makes the OP think we have schizophrenic people answering questions :)

Comment: `... Any cognitive resources that your brain expends ... won’t be available to help you work.`   I don't buy this part.  If I have no earphones on, the sounds of my neighbors, the sounds of the HVAC, etc are also being processed by my ears+brain.  Since I hear my alarm when I sleep, I think I can be pretty sure that my ears, and brain is processing sound pretty much always.

Comment: @blankip Sorry about that. I thought this would be better suited in the Skeptics SE, so I voted close.  And as it is a question which is relevant to a site, I went ahead and answered it  :)

Comment: @Zoredache if you're just trying to ignore the music you listen to like you ignore the HVAC then why do you want it?

Comment: @djechlin The difference is most likely due to familiarity.  If you're familiar with your music, your brain will spend less time being distracted by it.  The other noises would be distracting if you have particular sensitivity to it, like the sharp whirling sound of the HVAC or the particular words in nearby conversation.  I'm ok with HVAC.  I am absolutely unable to concentrate if there are conversations around me because I can pick up all the words and I'll naturally follow their conversations.

Comment: @Nelson Yeah, even I think the same  (already updated the answer an hour ago).  It's all about whether the brain is multi-tasking or not :)